# JSON content post request validation practice

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, validation, express

For NodeJS, Express 4,
Sometimes I write a route where client would send a JSON data of this kind to be processed,

```
{
   "data" : "xx" 
   "nested" : {
         field1: "111",
         field2: "222"
   } 
}
```

Then on server side, I often find myself doing a lot of manual validation such as

```
if (!validVariable(req.body.data)) //error
if (!validVariable(req.body.nested)) //error
if (validVariable(req.body.nested)) {
    if (!validVariable(req.body.nested.field1) // error
    if (!validVariable(req.body.nested.field2) // error
}
.....
function validVariable(input) {
    return (typeof input !== 'undefined') && input;
}
```

It is very tedious to always test the struct before safely accessing the post request content, if I go ahead and use req.body.nested.field1 I might crash the server due to null pointer exception from req.body.nested.

I don't think server validation of form content is this tedious? What do people normally do? 
I have looked at node-validator, express-validator and it seems really useful but testing the json data manually? Is there a better way?

And also, I get so wary of what data-type the client sent, to go further I am actually thinking of manually checking the datatype like ? isBoolen? isInt? isString etc. This sounds really tedious so any insight with javascript validation will be really helpful! 
Thank you!

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to have anything to do with JSON but rather with how to safely access nested objects. JSON is just text. Hopefully this helps you now to use better search terms and find an already existing question.

Comment: check http://json-schema.org they have validators in multiple languages

Answer (score 1):

Iv been using Ajv library for this purpose. And it has worked well for me. Simply do below

1) Define the schema of request you will be expecting. You will have to specify the required fields and the data type in the schema definition.

2) Import and install the library, validate request using

```
 var valid = ajv.validate(schema,request);
```

Check `valid` for status of validation and `ajv.errors` for details on what was wrong about the request.
For more details refer https://github.com/epoberezkin/ajv

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://github.com/hapijs/joi

You define a schema first, then validate your json.

Comment: This is really good! Any thoughts on https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator ?